# ASP - OnServerClick Doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET with C# 4.0.
My problem is that I want only one button to activate a certain method on server.
What do i mean? I'm glad you asked.
I have 2 buttons.[image: "Filter" and "FetchEvents"]
Any my aspx code is:

```
 <form id="form2" runat="server">
     <div class="box-generic">
         <div class="form-group well" style="">
            <input type="submit" name="button_filter" value="filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" id="all_events_button" name="all_events_button" value="All Events CSV" class="btn btn-primary" OnServerClick="downloadAllEvents" runat="server"/>  
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

If I press the "filter" button it works awesome.
Whenever I press the "All Events CSV" button, it works great.

**Scenario**

**1.**  Clicking on All Events.  (Activates the all events button normally)
**2.**  Clicking on Filter.

### downloadAllEvents() Method is being activated. BAD BAD BAD

And the weirdest part about it is that this method will be activated through filter only **after** it has been activated through AllEvents.

### EDIT:

I'm currently checking inside the method that the call didn't came from the filter button.
not a pretty sight.

Haven't found someone with the same problem.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where the onclick method for filter button is handled ?? also did u try using a normal button instead of submit for the filter ?

Comment: The filter button is "post" button. it sends a post request. I need it to be a submit button in order to get the dates to filter by.

Comment: It makes since if "All Events CSV" is calling the "filter" button as both will trigger the page_load... but this is strange... to be on the safe side and easy solution is use a normal button for the filter, and read the date from a server side control textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer I was hoping for, **BUT** it works and it works good. (Bugless)
In my `downloadAllEvents()` I check who sent the post request and I **deny** the post request from anyone who is not `all_events_button`

By doing so i transfer the responsibility from the sender to the listener.
If anyone has better answer please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a below sample page, and its working perfectly... can you POST the full page ... ?

Try this code and tell me what exactly is happening:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Am Load<br/>");
    }

    protected void downloadAllEvents(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Am Download");
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div class="box-generic">
            <div class="form-group well" style="">
                <input type="text" name="x" />
                <input type="submit" name="button_filter" value="filter" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <input type="button" id="all_events_button" name="all_events_button" value="All Events CSV" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="downloadAllEvents" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly i'm curerntly doing (Except that my Page_Load and donloadAllEvents methods are on the CodeBehind in the C# page and not in a JavaScript code.